# POST request response 422 error {'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid dict', 'type': 'type_error.dict'}]}

Tags: python, http-post, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-422

My `POST` request continues to fail with `422` response, even though valid `JSON` is being sent. I am trying to create a web app that receives an uploaded text file with various genetic markers and sends it to the tensorflow model to make a cancer survival prediction. The link to the github project can be found [here](https://github.com/Ryerson-BME-Capstone).

Here is the `POST` request:

```
 df_json = dataframe.to_json(orient='records')
 prediction = requests.post('http://backend:8080/prediction/', json=json.loads(df_json), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

And here is the pydantic model along with the API endpoint:

```
class Userdata(BaseModel):
RPPA_HSPA1A : float
RPPA_XIAP : float
RPPA_CASP7 : float
RPPA_ERBB3 :float
RPPA_SMAD1 : float
RPPA_SYK : float
RPPA_STAT5A : float
RPPA_CD20 : float
RPPA_AKT1_Akt :float
RPPA_BAD : float
RPPA_PARP1 : float
RPPA_MSH2 : float
RPPA_MSH6 : float
RPPA_ACACA : float
RPPA_COL6A1 : float
RPPA_PTCH1 : float
RPPA_AKT1 : float
RPPA_CDKN1B : float
RPPA_GATA3 : float
RPPA_MAPT : float
RPPA_TGM2 : float
RPPA_CCNE1 : float
RPPA_INPP4B : float
RPPA_ACACA_ACC1 : float
RPPA_RPS6 : float
RPPA_VASP : float
RPPA_CDH1 : float
RPPA_EIF4EBP1 : float
RPPA_CTNNB1 : float
RPPA_XBP1 : float
RPPA_EIF4EBP1_4E : float
RPPA_PCNA : float
RPPA_SRC : float
RPPA_TP53BP1 : float
RPPA_MAP2K1 : float
RPPA_RAF1 : float
RPPA_MET : float
RPPA_TP53 : float
RPPA_YAP1 : float
RPPA_MAPK8 : float
RPPA_CDKN1B_p27 : float
RPPA_FRAP1 : float
RPPA_RAD50 : float
RPPA_CCNE2 : float
RPPA_SNAI2 : float
RPPA_PRKCA_PKC : float
RPPA_PGR : float
RPPA_ASNS : float
RPPA_BID : float
RPPA_CHEK2 : float
RPPA_BCL2L1 : float
RPPA_RPS6 : float
RPPA_EGFR : float
RPPA_PIK3CA : float
RPPA_BCL2L11 : float
RPPA_GSK3A : float
RPPA_DVL3 : float
RPPA_CCND1 : float
RPPA_RAB11A : float
RPPA_SRC_Src_pY416 :float
RPPA_BCL2L111 : float
RPPA_ATM : float
RPPA_NOTCH1 : float
RPPA_C12ORF5 : float
RPPA_MAPK9 : float
RPPA_FN1 : float
RPPA_GSK3A_GSK3B : float
RPPA_CDKN1B_p27_pT198 : float
RPPA_MAP2K1_MEK1 : float
RPPA_CASP8 : float
RPPA_PAI : float
RPPA_CHEK1 : float
RPPA_STK11 : float
RPPA_AKT1S1 : float
RPPA_WWTR1 : float
RPPA_CDKN1A : float
RPPA_KDR : float
RPPA_CHEK2_2 : float
RPPA_EGFR_pY1173 : float
RPPA_EGFR_pY992 : float
RPPA_IGF1R : float
RPPA_YWHAE : float
RPPA_RPS6KA1 : float
RPPA_TSC2 : float
RPPA_CDC2 : float
RPPA_EEF2 : float
RPPA_NCOA3 : float
RPPA_FRAP1 : float
RPPA_AR : float
RPPA_GAB2 : float
RPPA_YBX1 : float
RPPA_ESR1 : float
RPPA_RAD51 : float
RPPA_SMAD4 : float
RPPA_CDH3 : float
RPPA_CDH2 : float
RPPA_FOXO3 : float
RPPA_ERBB2_HER : float
RPPA_BECN1 : float
RPPA_CASP9 : float
RPPA_SETD2 : float
RPPA_SRC_Src_mv : float
RPPA_GSK3A_alpha : float
RPPA_YAP1_pS127 : float
RPPA_PRKCA_alpha : float
RPPA_PRKAA1 : float
RPPA_RAF1_pS338 : float
RPPA_MYC : float
RPPA_PRKAA1_AMPK : float
RPPA_ERRFI1_MIG : float
RPPA_EIF4EBP1_2 : float
RPPA_STAT3 : float
RPPA_AKT1_AKT2_AKT3 : float
RPPA_NF2 : float
RPPA_PECAM1 : float
RPPA_BAK1 : float
RPPA_IRS1 : float
RPPA_PTK2 : float
RPPA_ERBB3_2 : float
RPPA_FOXO3_a : float
RPPA_RB1_Rb : float
RPPA_MAPK14_p38 : float
RPPA_NFKB1 : float
RPPA_CHEK1_Chk1 : float
RPPA_LCK : float
RPPA_XRCC5 : float
RPPA_PARK7 : float
RPPA_DIABLO : float
RPPA_CTNNA1 : float
RPPA_ESR1_ER : float
RPPA_IGFBP2 : float
RPPA_STMN1 : float
RPPA_WWTR1_TAZ : float
RPPA_CASP3 : float
RPPA_JUN : float
RPPA_CCNB1 : float
RPPA_CLDN7 : float
RPPA_PXN : float
RPPA_RPS6KB1_p : float
RPPA_KIT : float
RPPA_CAV1 : float
RPPA_PTEN : float
RPPA_BAX : float
RPPA_SMAD3 : float
RPPA_ERBB2 : float
RPPA_MET_c : float
RPPA_ERCC1 : float
RPPA_MAPK14 : float
RPPA_BIRC2 : float
RPPA_PIK3R1 : float
RPPA_BCL2 : float
RPPA_PEA : float
RPPA_EEF2K : float
RPPA_RPS6KB1_p70 : float
RPPA_MRE11A : float
RPPA_KRAS : float
RPPA_ARID1A : float
RPPA_YBX1_yb : float
RPPA_NOTCH3 : float
RPPA_EIF4EBP1_3 : float
RPPA_XRCC1 : float
RPPA_ANXA1 : float
RPPA_CD49 : float
RPPA_SHC1 : float
RPPA_PDK1 : float
RPPA_EIF4E : float
RPPA_MAPK1_MAPK3 : float
RPPA_PTGS2 : float
RPPA_PRKCA : float
RPPA_EGFR_egfr : float
RPPA_RAB25 : float
RPPA_RB1 : float
RPPA_MAPK1 : float
RPPA_TFF1 : float
    
class config:
    orm_mode = True
        
@app.post("/prediction/")
async def create_item(userdata: Userdata):
    df = pd.DataFrame(userdata)
    y = model.predict(df)
    y = [0 if val < 0.5 else 1 for val in y]
    if y == 1:
        survival = 'You will survive.'
    if y == 0:
        survival = 'You will not survive.'
    return {'Prediction': survival}
```

Comment: Your json fails somehow. What about changing the json parameter to: `json.dumps(json.loads(df_json))`

Comment: @stuck still receiving the same error using json.dumps. The json is properly formatted,  I don't believe that is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python `requests`, when sending `JSON` data using the `json` parameter, you need to pass a dict object (e.g., `json={"RPPA_HSPA1A":30,"RPPA_XIAP":-0.902044768}`), which `requests` will automatically encode into `JSON` and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. In your case, however, as you are using  [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method, the object you get (i.e., `df_json` as you define it) is a `JSON` encoded string (you could verify that by printing out `type(df_json)`). Thus, you should rather use [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method, which returns a dictionary instead. Since you are using `orient='records'`, the returned object will be a `list` of `dict`, and thus, you need to get the first element from that `list`. Example below:

```
data = dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
payload = data[0]
prediction = requests.post('<URL_HERE>', json=payload)
```

Otherwise, if you used `to_json()` method, you would need to use the `data` parameter when posting the request (see the documentation [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)), and as mentioned earlier, since you specify the orientation to `records` that returns a `list`, you would need to strip both the leading and trailing square brackets from that string. Also, using this method, you would need to manually set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Example below:

```
df_json = dataframe.to_json(orient='records')
payload = df_json.strip("[]")
prediction = requests.post('<URL_HERE>', data=payload, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue!

Comment: I'm having another issue now that the json is being passed, I'm trying to figure how to convert the pydantic model to a pandas dataframe to input into my tensorflow model. I'm now receiving a 500 response internal server error

Comment: For those using postman to make the request, select JSON from the drop-down as default is text

Comment: @ShirishBajpai Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73906755/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489056/17865804), if you are using Postman.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same issue in my least-cost feed formulation API, but I was trying to get results in postman and call API from React Native, I solved it by finding the headers in my request, previously `Content-Type` was set to some `plain text`, we need to tell that `Content-Type` is an `application/json`, and then it was giving response correctly